# proxy_pass based on headers without using if condition

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm looking for a way to reroute all requests that have set an account-id in the HTTP header `Account-ID` with the last two digits (of a ten digit number) `00` to `05` (to touch only 5% of the total traffic). In addition, if a request has set the HTTP header `Server-A`, that request should be forwarded to that server regardless of the set account-id. Otherwise and by default, all traffic should be handled by server-b. My current location-rule looks like this:

```
location /rest/accounts/ {
  if ( $http_account_id ~ '([\d]{8})(0[0-4])') {
    proxy_pass http://server-a.company.com;
  }

  if ( $http_server_a = true) {
    proxy_pass http://server-a.company.com;
  }

  proxy_pass http://server-b.company.com;
}
```

As I read in the official documents [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), `if` is considered *evil*.

Is there a better solution for my approach which isn't considered *evil*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually chain `map` directives a which would make it cleaner. For example:

```
map $http_server_a $server_a_check {
    default                 "http://server-b.company.com";
    ""                      "http://server-a.company.com";
}

map $http_account $account_check{
    default                 $server_a_check;
    "~([\d]{8})(0[0-4])"    "http://server-a.company.com";
}

server {
    ....
    location / {
        proxy_pass          $account_check;
    }
}
```

So `proxy_pass` is getting its value from `$account_check` which does a check against `Account` header with a regex check. Then if none of the variants pass their checks, the `default` gets its value from the result of `$server_a_check` which looks for `Server-A` header with no data for the value as the question didn't state what the accepted values would be.

Comment: Thank you very much, will give it a try and accept as soon as possible.

Comment: I accept the answer although I get a "502 Bad Gateway" if I enter `https://server-a` instead of `http://server-a...`

Comment: What if I need to set two variables at once?